# All the ajax calls on site suddenly stopped working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have few ajax function on the website. Friend add/remove etc. They are worked just fine and since 1 week they just doesn't.

Nothing appear on the console log. When I press the button nothing happen. I just don't know what can be the problem. Source of the pages it's not changed since 6 months. This is one of the scripts

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.newFriend, .buttons').click(function() {
$.post('misc/add_friend.php',
        {
            "id": $(this).attr('id')
        },
        function (response) {

            switch (response) {
                case 'Already friends':
                    $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Already friends!</div>');
                    $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                        $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                    });
                    break;
                case 'Trying to add themselves':
                    $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: red">You can't add yourself as a friend!</div>');
                    $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                        $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                    });
                    break;
                case 'Added as friend':
                    $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: red">You added this user as a friend!</div>');
                    $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                        $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                    });
                    break;
            }

        });

   });

});
```

and this is the button

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="newFriend has-tooltip pull-right" data-title="Add as a friend" id="'.$id.'" >
    <i class="fa fa-user" style="text-decoration: none;"></i> Add as a friend
</a>
```

Those are declaration that I use

```
<script src="css/js/jquery.confirm.min.js"></script>  
<script src="css/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>    
<script src="css/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use $.ajax to check the error

Comment: Please put jquery file `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` as the first script

Comment: That's right. You have to load jquery before you can load other jquery plugins.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the function, does it stop there when you click on the buttons?

Comment: I moved `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` as a first script -> same result. Doesn't even show the tooltip of the button. How can I put breakpoint in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to swap

```
 <script src="css/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="css/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="css/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="css/js/jquery.confirm.min.js"></script>  
 <script src="css/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. After swapping them I got the tooltip of the buttons. But still doesn't work and doesn't do add/remove when I press it. Also I don't see something wrong in browser console.

Comment: Try to remove comma from code: $('.newFriend .buttons').click(function() {

Comment: Actually yes. Swapping them is working. The problem was in `jquery.confirm.min.js` I don't what exactly but I downloaded fresh one and replaced mine. Now both ajax calls are working. Very strange and thank's for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It May be a cross-origin issue.ie http to  https ajax call
The host, port and scheme (protocol) must be the same in order for the AJAX request to work.